# Making complex logic easier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oop, model-view-controller

How do people organize complex methods?
I mean where do programmers usually put methods that don't really belong to any particular model, but instead use 3-4 models and 2-3 scopes to make some complex decisions?

For example, the heart of app I'm working on right now is following script:

```
@items_to_post = Item.where(calendar_id: Ad.ready_to_post.collect(&:calendar_id).uniq).not_posted_yet(ad)
if @items_to_post.renewable.count > 0
  @output = "Please Renew First"
else
  @first_item = @items_to_post.first
  @post = Post.new(title: @first_item.randomizations.first.title, body: @first_item.description, ... )
  ...
end
```

I just don't want to bore you with entire code - it's very long, and needs to be called in two places with small differences.

I've put all this to my ExportController, which is ugly, especially for Controller, because it breaks MVC convention, but I have no idea what to do about it.

Where do you guys usually put methods like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single responsibility principle : Give each job to a separate class that only knows about (takes the dependencies for) the things it needs to do its job. If you make these responsibilities small, the number of dependencies for each class will be low, and the classes will be simple. It may make your code as a whole more complicated, but that's OK as you don't have to look at it all at once.

If you actually post more of your code, people might be able to suggest some of the responsibilities that can be split out into separate classes.

Comment: After reading your answer a couple times - I finally understood "who should do this job". Thanks.

Comment: Glad if it made some sense. As a note on MVC - personally when I see classes called '______Controller', I get scared, because people often put way too much code and logic into 'Controllers'.

Comment: Yep I don't like that too. Controller just responds to requests. That's why I asked how to move it out.